# MongoDB/mongoose: query array field elements to match a part of a string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**GIVEN**

a searchString `"*** test text before string *** john doe | test string after string"`

**AND**

a MongoDB document:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "matchingWords": [
    "john doe", "another string"
  ]
}
```

**I WANT TO** query for any documents that have at least 1 element in the matchingWords field (string[]) that is found in the searchString.
!! The elements in matchingWords might contains spaces.

**Expected result**: the mongoDB document above is found because element "john doe" is found in the searchString.

**Problem**

The code below is only working when matchingWords elements do not contain spaces... And I cannot find a solution to fulfill my requirement. So please help me :-)

```
private async findByMatchingWords(searchString: string): Promise<boolean> {
if (!searchString) return false;

const lowerCaseSearchStrings: string[] = searchString.toLowerCase().split(' ');
const results = await paymentPartyModel
  .find<IPaymentParty>({
    matchingWords: {
      $exists: true,
      $not: { $size: 0 }, // Check if array exists and is not empty
      $in: lowerCaseSearchStrings,
    },
  })
  .lean();

if (!results || results.length === 0) {
  return false;
} else if (results.length === 1) {
  this.info = results[0];
  return true;
} else {
  // 2 or more matches found...
  Todo('What to do when more than one payment party matches the search?');
  return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$indexOfCP` to check for the existence of the matchingWords within the substring. If the matchingWord is not inside, it would return -1. `$map` this result to an array of boolean from `matchingWords` array. Use `$anyElementTrue` to check for **any** words that are within the search string.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $anyElementTrue: {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "searchString": "*** test text before string *** john doe | test string after string"
        },
        "in": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$matchingWords",
            "as": "mw",
            "in": {
              "$ne": [
                -1,
                {
                  "$indexOfCP": [
                    "$$searchString",
                    "$$mw"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kuGRwoJtve_)

Comment: This works perfect! 2 additional questions to make it perfect... 
1) Can I easily make this case insensitive?
2) Should I create an index to optimize this query? If yes, how?

Comment: Found answer to question 1 myself ;-)
```$indexOfCP: [{ $toLower: '$$searchString' }, { $toLower: '$$mw' }]```

Comment: @b_it_s That could be a much boarder question when we come into indexes and performance tuning. [Text index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/) could be one of the starting points. Anyway, to keep the current question focused and concise, consider asking a new question and provide link to this question for context.